# Setting and Getting version of the JAR file in Android Studio programmatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, jar

I'm developing a library and exporting it as a jar file via gradle commands,I'm using this library in another application.
I'm trying to set a version for the exported jar file and moreover I'd like to get this version number programmatically in the second application.

I've tried a lot of approaches on the internet ,but the didn't work work for me.
Currently I'm using these lines in the build.gradle of the library project set the version,but I couldn't succeed in getting the version in the second app.

```
defaultConfig {
        versionCode 01
        versionName "1.0.0"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22

    }
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Great regards

Comment: Write a method in your library project that returns version number and call it in your project which is more easier,

Comment: @SeshuVinay  So,how can I get the context in my library code,I mean I'm not in an activity so I need to pass a context to the method,but when I use it in my second application I have to pass an activity which is in the second one not in the library,so it returns the version of the current app .How can I achieve this goal? { CustomVersion v=new CustomVersion(MainActivity.this);
        String sss=v.GetVersion();}

Comment: android studio is not eclipse...so please don't tag android studio related questions with eclipse.